# Access row in Telerik Grid in MVC2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, watin

I am using telerik grid in mvc2 application. I have to perform Watin UI test for my application. For that i need to select a row from the telerik grid. I was not able to select id for the telerik grid as the telerik grid doesn't have any id. can u  please help me to select the particular row from the grid. I have 6 columns in the grid. Based on the value of a row in the  column(should iterate though the column) i need to select the id of that row and hit on the  select button of that row.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik MVC Grid always has an ID attribute which is basically the value specified by the Name() method. I suggest you check the generated output.

I don't have any experience with Watin but it should be possible to use its API to traverse table rows and extract the values of the cells.